# Is there a downside to long URLs?

Tags: seo, url-routing

For sake of SEO I'd like to begin using my Blog's title as the URL (just like SO). Is there a point where long is too long? Any browser-specific (IE6) issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Search engines may trip over query strings (the part behind the `?`) but the length of the url shouldn't be a problem as long as you keep it under 8Kb.

But, a nice, short, clean and readable url might convince more vistors to actually click on it.

Comment: Here's some additional info regarding older browsers
from http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring/get/url-parameters.html
The spec for URL length does not dictate a minimum or maximum URL length, but implementation varies by browser. On Windows: Opera supports ~4050 characters, IE 4.0+ supports exactly 2083 characters, Netscape 3 -> 4.78 support up to 8192 characters before causing errors on shut-down, and Netscape 6 supports ~2000 before causing errors on start-up.

In short, shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually SEO suggests that you do not overuse the title of your blog, but rather make your post's title more important. That is why it is not a very good idea to use your blog title in a single post title as well. The header is an important part and the keywords of your post title should not be mixed with the title of your blog (because this makes them less important).

However, rest assured that google already knows about these ideas and handles them properly. Therefore, i would advise you not to pay too much attention on such matters.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the earlier the keyword is in the url the more weight it is given. If you are trying to optimize for the keyword "widgets" url A is going to be beneficial, and url B likely will not.

A: yoursite.com/Widgets-For-Sale

B: yoursite.com/This-Is-A-Blog-Post-About-Widgits